# How to set cursor position for UITextView on user input?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitextview

*I am looking for a simple answer for this problem...*

I have a `UITextView` in which the user can start typing and click on DONE and resign the keyboard.

When the wants to edit it again, I want the cursor (the blinking line) to be at the first position of the `textView`, not at the end of textView. **(act like a placeholder)**

I tried `setSelectedRange` with `NSMakeRange(0,0)` on `textViewDidBeginEditing`, but it does not work.

#### More Info:

It can be seen that.. when the user taps on the `textView` the `cursor` comes up at the position where the user taps on the `textView`.

I want it to always blink at starting position when `textViewDidBeginEditing`.

Comment: See if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500233/control-cursor-position-in-uitextfield

Comment: @tipycalFlow : Thanks, but I already checked that. It's unrelated to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up adding a UILabel over the `UITextView` which acts as a placeholder for the textView. Tapping on the UILabel would send the action down to the textView and `becomeFirstResponder`. Once you start typing, make the label hidden.

Comment: Seems incredibly hacky. Why not a UIView instead of a UILabel?

Comment: @fatuhoku: '...UILabel over the UITextView which acts as a placeholder for the textView'

Answer (score 19):

The property selectedRange can not be assigned at "any place", to make it work you have to implement the method `- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView`, in your case:

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [textView setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(0, 0)];
}
```

you will have to detect when the user is beginning editing or selecting text

Comment: This is the best solution I've come across yet. This should really be the top answer!

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Legend! Searching on stack overflow is always faster than read the doc :)

Answer (score 11):

My solution:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
    textView.text = @"This is a test";
    [self.view addSubview: textView];
    textView.delegate = self;
    [textView release];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(tapped:)];
    [textView addGestureRecognizer: tap];
    [tap release];
}
- (void) tapped: (UITapGestureRecognizer *) tap {
    [textView becomeFirstResponder];
} 

- (void) textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0);
}
```

I guess it's UITextView internal mechanism to set the cursor when user taps on it. We need to override that by attaching a tap gesture recognizer and call `becomeFirstResponder` instead.

Comment: The link you posted in invalid - `Unknown Paste ID!`

Comment: Hello, One help my code not display input cursor using custom keyboard ?

Answer (score 7):

I was facing the same issue - basically there's a delay when becoming first responder that doesn't allow you to change `selectedRange` in any of `textView*BeginEditing:` methods. If you try to delay the `setSelectedRange:` (let's say with `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`) it shows ugly jerk.

The solution is actually pretty simple - checking order of delegate methods gives you the hint:

1. `textViewShouldBeginEditing:`
2. `textViewDidBeginEditing:`
3. `textViewDidChangeSelection:`

Setting `selectedRange` in the last method (3) does the trick, you just need to make sure you reposition the cursor only for the first time when the `UITextView` becomes first responder as the method (3) is called every time you update the content.

A BOOL variable set in `shouldChangeTextInRange:` <strike>one of the methods (1), (2)</strike> and check for the variable in (3) should do the trick ... just don't forget to reset the variable after the reposition to avoid constant cursor reset :).

Hope it helps!

#### EDIT

After few rounds of testing I decided to set the BOOL flag in `shouldChangeTextInRange:` instead of (2) or (3) as it proved to be more versatile. See my code:

```
@interface MyClass
{
    /** A flag to determine whether caret should be positioned (YES - don't position caret; NO - move caret to beginning). */
    BOOL _isContentGenerated;
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    // deleting
    if([text length] == 0)
    {
        // deleting last character
        if(range.length == [[textView text] length])
        {
            // reached beginning
            /** 
             code to show placeholder and reset caret to the beginning 
            */
            _isContentGenerated = NO;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // adding
        if(range.location == 0)
        {
            /** 
             code to hide placeholder
            */
            _isContentGenerated = YES;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if(!_isContentGenerated)
    {
        [textView setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(0, 0)];
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, but could be improved by adding code.

Comment: @meaning-matters Now, that's what I call Christmas :D Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked enough with that to help you fully, but what happens when you try to play with different `selectedRange`s? Say, if you do `[... setSelectedRange:[NSMakeRange(0,1)]]` or `[... setSelectedRange:[NSMakeRange(1,0)]]`? Does it move the cursor anywhere?

Comment: Hm. It's just like how I have stated in my question. It does not work. Cursor position  = position of User Tap.

Comment: If it doesn't change the behavior, it sounds like it doesn't call your `setSelectedRange` at all. Put a breakpoint on the call and follow it through?

Comment: It does call it. My concern is that - that does not fix the issue.

Answer (score -4):

```
[_detailAreaView setTextContainerInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 11, 8, 11)];
```

Comment: This isn't related to the question, this just shows how to create an inset thus moving the text position within the textview.