# UITapGestureRecognizer fire in UITextView once

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I need set cursor in UITextView in first position when user tapped UITextView. `NSMakeRange` didn't help me, but I find solution in [How to set cursor position for UITextView on user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135086/how-to-set-cursor-position-for-uitextview-on-user-input)

And I add tapGesture in my UITextView. But it work only once, at first time, why?

```
textViewMessage.gestureRecognizers = nil;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapTextView = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapTextView)];
[textViewMessage addGestureRecognizer:tapTextView];
```

and this method called only once

```
- (void)tapTextView
{
    [textViewMessage becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's only called once? It could very well be that you're not noticing it the second time because the textView in question is already the first responder, thus nothing is happening on screen.

Comment: i add breakpoint in this method and it's only once in first tap called. Then i choose textFields on screen and then again tap UITextView, but it become firstResponder without calling my method. And cursor don't in the beggining of my text, except first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the textView becomes first responder, you couldn't catch the touch events over it. I found a hackish way quickly but I'm sure you can find a better one.

```
- (void)tapTextView
{
    [textViewMessage setEditable:YES];
    [textViewMessage becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    if ([textView isFirstResponder]) {
        [textView setEditable:NO];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

You need to add UITextViewDelegate to your header file. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Subclass UITextView and add the following methods:

```
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    BOOL result = [super becomeFirstResponder];

    if (result)
    {
        //Take your cursor to any position you want
    }
    return result;
}

- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder
{
    BOOL result = [super resignFirstResponder];

    if (result)
    {
        //Do anything you need when text view resigns
    }
    return result;
}
```