# UITextField set cursor to start text position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I need to move cursor to start text position on set focus on the textfield.  Is it possible tot do?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Set your view controller (or some other appropriate object) as the text field's `delegate` and implement the `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` method like this:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UITextPosition *beginning = [textField beginningOfDocument];
    [textField setSelectedTextRange:[textField textRangeFromPosition:beginning
                                                          toPosition:beginning]];
}
```

Note that `setSelectedTextRange:` is a protocol method of `UITextInput` (which `UITextField` implements), so you won't find it directly in the `UITextField` documentation.

Comment: I set this code but it dose not work for me and textfield's cursor dose not set at end of text. can help me?

Answer (score 4):

```
self.selectedTextRange = [self textRangeFromPosition:newPos toPosition:newPos];
```

Check this [Finding the cursor position in a UITextField](http://neofight.wordpress.com/2012/04/01/finding-the-cursor-position-in-a-uitextfield/)

Answer (score 4):

If anyone's looking for the answer in Swift:

```
let desiredPosition = textField.beginningOfDocument
textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRangeFromPosition(desiredPosition, toPosition: desiredPosition)
```

But I believe this only works if the cursor is already in the text field. You can use this to do that:

```
textField.becomeFirstResponder()
let desiredPosition = textField.beginningOfDocument
textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRangeFromPosition(desiredPosition, toPosition: desiredPosition)
```

Comment: when i use this code and select my cursor at first of text, cursor set at first but I don't want to that