# iOS: Programmatically move cursor up, down, left and right in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, position, cursor, uitextview

I use the following code to move the cursor position to 5 characters from the beginning of a `UITextField`:

```
 txtView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(5, 0);
```

Now, if I have a cursor at an arbitrary position as shown in the image below, how can I move the cursor up, down, left and right?

[image]

Comment: Right & left, that's easy, it's just that instead of `NSMakeRange(something, 0);` something +1 or -1 (be careful of the bounds). For up/down, that's more tricky, because you have to know the line, the current range according to the position in that line. Maybe some possible leads there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557845/uitextview-get-the-current-line

Comment: maybe this one helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931227/uitextfield-set-cursor-to-start-text-position

Comment: @NiravKotecha No, the problem here is different.

Comment: @Larme Ok, I will implement it myself then. I was hoping to find a more elegant solution.

Comment: Add your current scenario (Detail process) so others can understand well and they will you help you :)

Answer (score 2):

Left and right should be more or less easy. I guess the tricky part is top and bottom. I would try the following.

You can use `caretRect` method to find the current "frame" of the cursor:

```
if let cursorPosition = answerTextView.selectedTextRange?.start {
    let caretPositionRect = answerTextView.caretRect(for: cursorPosition)


}
```

Then to go up or down, I would use that frame to calculate estimated position in `UITextView` coordinates using `characterRange(at:)` (or maybe `closestPosition(to:)`), e.g. for up:

```
let yMiddle = caretPositionRect.origin.y + (caretPositionRect.height / 2)
let lineHeight = answerTextView.font?.lineHeight ?? caretPositionRect.height // default to caretPositionRect.height
// x does not change
let estimatedUpPoint = CGPoint(x: caretPositionRect.origin.x, y: yMiddle - lineHeight)
if let newSelection = answerTextView.characterRange(at: estimatedUpPoint) {
    // we have a new Range, lets just make sure it is not a selection
    newSelection.end = newSelection.start

    // and set it
    answerTextView.selectedTextRange = newSelection
} else {
    // I guess this happens if we go outside of the textView
}
```

I haven't really done it before, so take this just as a general direction that should work for you.

Documentation to the methods used is [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput).