# How to change the starting cursor position inside UITextView

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I have a uitextview which become the first responder on viewload. but i want to change the position of the cursor of the uitextview at certain position in x for the first 2 line only.

Comment: mainy delegate methods of uitextview from google but none work @d4Rk

Comment: Can you show us some code, and whats not working? Or what you expect it to do.

Comment: I just want to do it like facebook screens for status update in android

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use a UITextKit ([a very good tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50151/text-kit-tutorial)).

For example to have a rounded text you can use something like:

```
UIBezierPath* exclusionPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:yourTextView.bounds];
exclusionPath = [exclusionPath bezierPathByReversingPath];
yourTextView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[exclusionPath];
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried following solutions ?

Controlling cursor position in a UITextField is complicated because so many abstractions are involved with input boxes and calculating positions. However, it's certainly possible. You can use the member function `setSelectedTextRange`:

```
[input setSelectedTextRange:[input textRangeFromPosition:start toPosition:end]];
```

Here's a function which takes a range and selects the texts in that range. If you just want to place the cursor at a certain index, just use a range with length 0:

```
+ (void)selectTextForInput:(UITextField *)input atRange:(NSRange)range {
    UITextPosition *start = [input positionFromPosition:[input beginningOfDocument] 
                                                 offset:range.location];
    UITextPosition *end = [input positionFromPosition:start
                                               offset:range.length];
    [input setSelectedTextRange:[input textRangeFromPosition:start toPosition:end]];
}
```

For example, to place the cursor at `idx` in the UITextField `input`:

```
    [Helpers selectTextForInput:input 
                        atRange:NSMakeRange(idx, 0)];
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11532718/914111

Have not tested due to some busy so please let us know wether it is working or not (May have issue in IOS8.0)