# UITextView can't see from top

Tags: ios, uitextview

When the `UITextView`'s content is too much, the location of the cursor is in the middle rather than at the beginning. I want to start from the beginning rather than starting from the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,  `[yourTextView setSelectedTextRange:[yourTextView textRangeFromPosition:requiredCursorPosition toPosition:requiredCursorPosition]];`

For more refer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11532718/3743322

Comment: -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{ [super viewWillAppear:animated]; CGFloat contentHeight = self.textView.contentSize.height; CGFloat offSet = self.textView.contentOffset.x; CGFloat contentOffset = contentHeight - offSet; self.textView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -contentOffset);  I solved it by this ,thank you anymore